# Cloudflare Steam video not working in firefox

Tags: firefox, cloudflare, cloudflarestream

Hi I have implemented cloudflare stream video service in one of the website I am developing. The video used to play just fine but since the last 2 days it is broken in Firefox. It works fine in Chrome but won’t work in firefox.

The console gives throws up the error -

```
Specified “type” attribute of “application/x-mpegurl” is not supported. Load of media resource https://videodelivery.net/6aaee8579a7a98ccad84660514efe586/manifest/video.m3u8 failed. (https://www.checkbayt.com/home)

Specified “type” attribute of “application/dash+xml” is not supported. Load of media resource https://videodelivery.net/6aaee8579a7a98ccad84660514efe586/manifest/video.mpd failed.
```

My website is located at https://www.checkbayt.com/ in case anyone wants to try it out. I have also tried to rule out issues that might be caused due to some other code in the website and did a simple html page that only has the video and nothing else. Once again this used to work fine previously and I ran the same html file in firefox and it no longer works and gives the same error.

Is this something that anyone in here also experienced? I guess this is something to do with firefox and will get resolved from their end? Or do I need to do something different?

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping the stream script after the video. Not really sure why but i faced the same issue and render the script directly after the stream helped.

Note: the element should be loaded before the script as the script injects html elements into the stream tags.